# Why doesn't type-script support referencing javascript files?

Tags: typescript

I noticed that using /// <reference path="*.js"> doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Just a clarification: I KNOW about d.ts files, and I know what value is added by creating them to decorate a js file - they allow me to enjoy type-safety even when using an external library which wasn't written in typescript.

What I don't understand is why I still have to write a d.ts file even if I'm willing to forgoe type-safety.

Let's assume, for example, that I have a big JS file I have written, which contains many function definitions. These functions have names and lists of parameters. Can't the TS compiler automatically 'declare' those functions for usage? It would be a temporary solution, but it would facilitate migrating to TypeScript so much!

Is there a reason I'm missing that this is not possible, or is it just an unimplemented feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing a JavaScript file as a reference path won't work because references are solely used to build upon the type information for your program and a JavaScript file cannot supply this type information (although if you drop your JavaScript code into a `.ts` file, you'll find out how far away you are from inferring the types).

You don't have to write a `.d.ts` file if you don't want type checking... you just tell the compiler that you don't want type checking. For example, if you wanted to use jQuery without any type checking...

```
declare var $: any;

$("anything").whateverIsTypedWillBeAllowed("like this");
```

The first line says "I'm going to be using a var named `$` and I don't care about type safety when I use it".

Comment: While the jQuery.js file doesn't have any type information, it does have function and 'class' definitions - why can't TS use that? Not as good as a full d.ts file, but better than no type checking at all

Comment: You can paste the whole of jQuery into a TypeScript file if you want to see how much can be inferred - this will give you an idea of the scale of things. Once you have written a few definition files, you realise how much is missing from plain JS.

Comment: I suppose, but wouldn't it be categorized under "better than nothing"?

Comment: Try it out - if you can get your JavaScript to at least compile in a TypeScript file you can switch on 'generate type definitions' on the TypeScript compiler and you get a free .d.ts file.