# Angular2-Webpack-Typescript - 3rd party libraries

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, immutable.js

I've started with a beautiful seed project: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

And I've stuck with using 3rd-party modules.Can someone help/explain how to properly add/use external modules to this project?

For example, I'm adding 'immutable' using:

```
npm install immutable --save
```

After that, I'm trying to link that module inside a component:

```
import * as immutable from 'immutable';
import {List} from 'immutable';
import Immutable = require('immutable');
```

Nothing helps, it always returns TS2307: Cannot find module '`immutable`'. The same for '`moment`' for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typings file you need to add to your project that is located in `node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.d.ts`. You need to reference that in your project. It should look something like this:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts" />
import * as immutable from 'immutable';
import {List} from 'immutable';
import Immutable = require('immutable');
```

For moment there are typings available at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/moment). I recommend using [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) to install them.

If you come across a library you would like to use that you can't find any typings for, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts) for an easy way to still use it. You just won't get any of the Typescript benefits.

Comment: @Alexey Yes. You can it to the "files" section of your [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file. If you're using the exclude syntax, just make sure it's not excluded. I also edited my answer to provide a link to the moment typings.

Comment: @rgvassar ...and if lib doesn't have typescript definitions?

Comment: @deostroll The last part of my answer contains a link to another question, which addresses that exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Add the below to your main.ts file.

```
import 'immutable'
```

This should give you access to the imputable api within all your components without the need for any additional importing.

Comment: Could you suggest algorithms of actions for libraries that doesn't include types? 'moment' for example?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a possible workaround for people who are using a third party (npm) javascript module for which there is no typings definition and want to get rid of the "cannot find module" error message

Suppose you use the npm package [jsonapi-serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonapi-serializer) and you reference it in your `example.ts` file:

```
import {Serializer, Deserializer} from "jsonapi-serializer";

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  var deserializer = new Deserializer({ keyForAttribute: 'camelCase'});
}
```

The compiler will complain: `Error:(1, 40) TS2307:Cannot find module 'jsonapi-serializer'.`

You can declare the typings definition yourself by creating the following file: `jsonapi-serializer.d.ts`. You have to specify the main functions, but using the `any` type you can keep it relatively simple. (Consider [donating](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html) the definition file if you create a complete definition):

```
declare module 'jsonapi-serializer' {

    export class Serializer {
        constructor(type: string, ...options: any[]);
        serialize(arg: any)
    }

    export  class Deserializer {
        constructor(...options: any[]);
        deserialize()
    }
}
```

If you place this file in your project the compiler will recognize the module. When this doesn't work you can also reference it from your `ExampleService.ts` file by placing the following line on top of the file:

```
///<reference path="jsonapi-serializer.d.ts"/>
```