# How to include Third party javascript library in angular2 webpack typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, webpack

I am using  https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter as seed project and it's awesome.

But i can't understand how to include third party JS lib in my project using Webpack. I know it can be done using `<script src="third/party"></script>` But i want to do it in angular way like `import { ThirdParty } from 'third-part/';`

And Also please suggest the standard way to use javascript library in angular2 project using webpack.

Comment: These links should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638027/angular2-webpack-typescript-3rd-party-libraries               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166168/how-to-use-moment-js-library-in-angular-2-typescript-app/36290343#36290343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the import statement in your `src/vendor.ts` file, this should do the trick.

if not, you may have to resort to the `<script></script>`

Comment: and content inside the vendor.ts