# PrimeNG (PrimeUI) + Webpack + angular2 + typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

Is here anybody who know how to make PrimeNG under Webpack working?

We have project on [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) but the PrimeNG have todo just with System.js loader

I get the point when the PrimeNG is loading fine, but i can get success with PrimeUI library... let say for example file `primeng/components/togglebutton/togglebutton.ts`

> error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'PrimeUI'.

I even [tried magic formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts) with declare in `...togglebutton.ts`

```
declare var PrimeUI:any;
```

and in my `webpack.config`

```
plugins: [ 
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    PrimeUI: 'primeui',
  })
  .
  .
 ],
```

but if I try something like

```
import * as PrimeUI from 'primeui';
```

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'primeui'.

I just remind I did `npm install primeui` and the `primeui` is present in `node_modules` with all dependencies

Comment: We'll probably switch to common.js and provide a sample quickstart with webpack soon. d.ts for PrimeUI is at https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/showcase/resources/primeui/primeui.d.ts

Comment: PrimeNG uses commonjs as of 0.6.0

Comment: Have got PrimeNG running? Loading PrimeNG and PrimeUI is working for me but i do get JQuery errors.

Comment: I stop trying that. For now I using just jQuery DataTable and Select2 based on bootstrap

Comment: There is a PrimeNG+WebPack sample here. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-webpack

Comment: Here is a fork of angular2-webpack-starter that adds PrimeNG for the UI. https://github.com/cagataycivici/angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error on :

```
import * as PrimeUI from 'primeui';
```

You need to do

```
declare module 'primeui' {
    var foo:any;
    export = foo
}
```

Comment: Thank you, where should be the "declare module.. " ?

Comment: in a file `global.d.ts`