# Drawing path using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

Ive started to use ngx-leaflet, and cant find anyway of drawing path (going on real roads not just a polyline) between two markers, does such an option exists at all? 
tnx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include leaflet-routing-machine into angular 2 typescript webpack application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614323/how-to-include-leaflet-routing-machine-into-angular-2-typescript-webpack-applica)

Comment: No, thats not my issue, i did started using leaflet-routing-machine, but for some reason i cant find, on every request that i send i get the following error:

message:"Too Many Requests"

with status code of 429

Comment: Then please be specific about your problem. Is this about integrating a route-finding service into your angular stuff, or about an error with the OSRM backend? Take a moment to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask