# Is it possible to instantiate a JavaScript object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an existing JavaScript "class" , which is defined like this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

(I know there are no actual classes in JavaScript prior to ES6)

This class needs to be used inside a Angular2 component written in TypeScript. Normally, I would simply instantiate it like this:

```
var john = new Person('John Doe', 22);
```

When compiling the TypeScript code into JavaScript I will get an error saying `Cannot find name 'Person'`, since Person is not a TypeScript class.

Is there any solution to use the existing JavaScript class, without rewriting it into TypeScript?

Comment: What about just omitting the `new`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I still get the same error.

Comment: Seems Grezegorz approach should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts

Comment: Note that JavaScript doesn't *really* have classes even in ES 6, its just syntactic sugar over the regular patterns. You can still mess with `Person.prototype` even in ES 6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe try

```
declare var Person:any; // Magic
var john = new Person('John Doe', 22);
```

Answer (score 0):

Grzesiek's answer worked for me but I required a small modification.

My JS object was buried a couple of functions deep (to emulate namespacing) & was instantiated like:

`new MyCorp.Utils.UsefulThing();`

Because I had to place the declaration within a TS namespace I then had to mark it with 'export' for it to be visible to the TS code (which was in a different namespace) so I ended up with:

```
namespace MyCorp.Utils {
    export declare var UsefulThing: any;
}
```