# how to use javascript file(function) in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

how to use JavaScript file(function) in typescript.

```
//abc.js
function Abc(){
alert();
}
```

//test.ts
now how to use `Abc()` function in typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use an external non-typescript library from typescript without .d.ts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution:

```
declare var Abc: any;
Abc();
```

Comment: Using this defeats the purpose of using typescript. As soon as you use any, all bets are off an you have no type safety.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

lib.ts

```
export default class Lib {
    public Abc() {
        alert();
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import Lib from "./lib"

var lib = new Lib();
lib.Abc();
```

Comment: that is not  solution. where is .js file my question is how to import js file in .ts file and how to use .js file function.