# How to use a function from .js file in my controller.ts file in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use some function of my `sample.js` file which is located in my `src` folder:

```
var jsdata = new Object();
jsdata.getItem = function (pType, pIndex) {
    ...
};
```

Now in my controller typescript file I want to access this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
export class TestPage {
  item: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.item = jsdata.getItem('A', 1); 
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
  }
}
```

But jsdata is unkonwn. How to fix this?

Comment: Thats very unusual. The angular way is to create a provider with the function(s) and inject in your component

Comment: sample.js has been created by you or is it an external library ?

Comment: It was created by me.

Comment: I think you should write it like a node_module and import it like other module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts