# How to ignore TypeScript error TS2339 - Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, fabricjs

I'm using Angular 8 (started a project within Visual Studio 2019) and have `fabric.init.ts` file with next content:

```
import 'fabric';
import * as fabric from 'fabric/fabric-impl';

// (TS) Property 'DPI' does not exist on type 'typeof import(..@types/fabric/fabric-impl)'
fabric.DPI = 213;
....
```

Next is ok, because it matches the d.ts definition:

```
// Override fabric to meet ourrequirements
fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
  centeredRotation: true,
```

**How to ignore the `DPI` TS2339 error. It would be really great to have autocompletion, specially for learning fabric.**

My package.json:

```
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
  ....
  "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
  "@types/fabric": "3.5.1",
  "fabric": "3.5.1",
  ...
},
```

**EDIT**

For now I solved it by adding this line:

```
// @ts-ignore
fabric.DPI = 213;
```

I know its not the best solution, I prefer @wentjun's solution.

By changing this: `import * as fabric from 'fabric/fabric-impl';` to `import { fabric } from 'fabric';` I now have VisualStudio intellisense enabled as well. Of course I added @types/fabricjs to package.json.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For instance like this `(fabric as any).DPI = 213;`

Answer (score 2):

Either type cast it as any then Typescript will ignore it  like Vugar suggested or

import [Typescript definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fabric)

Comment: The problem is because fabric definition file does not have everything as fabric javascript file.

Comment: Try using fabricjs 1.5 or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Fabric, but the recommended way of doing so would be to extend the `fabric` namespace to accept DPI as a valid property.

First, you can create a typescript file and define your new fabric definition.

custom-fabric.ts:

```
interface ExtendedFabric {
  DPI: number;
}

// apply additional types to fabric and export it for usage
export const CustomFabric: (ExtendedFabric & typeof fabric) = fabric as any;
```

In your class/component that uses it,

```
import { CustomFabric } from './custom-fabric';

CustomFabric.DPI = 213; // no TS errors
```